# Avalanche Cluster Nodes stops automatically with out any error

Tags: ethereum, avalanche

I tried to setup avalanche cluster nodes using avalanche-network-runner
https://docs.avax.network/subnets/network-runner

I was able to run the nodes, but then after a while the nodes stop like below

````
[node1] INFO [11-24|17:23:12.281] <C Chain> github.com/ava-labs/coreth/core/blockchain.go:787: State manager shut down t="51.625µs"
[node1] INFO [11-24|17:23:12.281] <C Chain> github.com/ava-labs/coreth/core/blockchain.go:794: Shutting down sender cacher 
[node1] INFO [11-24|17:23:12.281] <C Chain> github.com/ava-labs/coreth/core/blockchain.go:798: Closing scope 
[node1] INFO [11-24|17:23:12.281] <C Chain> github.com/ava-labs/coreth/core/blockchain.go:802: Waiting for trie re-journal to complete 
[node1] INFO [11-24|17:23:12.281] <C Chain> github.com/ava-labs/coreth/core/blockchain.go:805: Blockchain stopped 
[11-24|17:23:12.292] INFO local/network.go:740 done stopping network
terminated network %!s(<nil>)
[11-24|17:23:12.292] INFO ux/output.go:14 terminated network %!s(<nil>)
[11-24|17:23:12.292] INFO server/server.go:376 no custom chain installation request, skipping its readiness check```

Not sure what is the issue here.
````